# What can I do if I have no saplings?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-skyfactory

I scared myself earlier playing the SkyFactory mod.

I used my saplings to make dirt, but then realised I didn't have any saplings to grow trees with.

Luckily I had seeds to make more trees, but if I didn't, what could I do to rectify the situation? Am I just completely screwed?

Do I have any means of getting an extra sapling if I would be to lose all my ways to make trees?

Comment: I just wrote a long answer until I saw the "skyfactory" tag. This should be in the question.

Comment: Sorry, added the name of the mod in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on how far you are in the game. As usual in modded Minecraft, there are many ways to get something.

When you hover over a sapling in the Not Enough Items (or however that variation of the mod is called) item list and press R (or another key, if you changed the keybind), you should see all possible ways to get that item.

In the case of saplings I'm pretty sure that I've seen it in a lootbag before, so you could build a mob farm. As long as you have some opaque blocks, that should be possible.

But in general it's always a good idea to leave a few saplings save in a chests that you never use, just in case. It's like the skyblock equivalent of "never dig straight down".

Comment: Funny how a SkyFactory answer is in my top 19% of highest voted answers, even though I never played SkyFactory.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a sieve you could sift dirt. However, this is a tough challenge due to the low drop rate.

[Sieved items](http://ex-nihilo-minecraft.wikia.com/wiki/Sieved_Items)